# Can't see what I type in the new mobile chat

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-safari, keyboard

[image]

I just can't scroll to the bottom to see what I type in when I open the keyboard.

- App Version: 1.4.2.2
- Device: iPad 2 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)

Comment: Why not link it to the question that yours is duplicated to?

Comment: Just wanted to show how silly it was we both couldn't find the duplicate...